# django dictionary of querysets

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

i made  i dictionary of querysets in one of my views :

```
list =[]


while(x<100 and i>0):


    order_qs_1 = Order.objects.filter(timestamp__range=[start_date, end_date])

    x = x+1
    i=i-j
    list.append(order_qs_1)
    context= {

    'list':list,

    }
```

but now i don't know how  to access the data inside the dictionary in my template

in my template i did something like this :

```
{% for item in list %}
{{ item }}   </br>
{% endfor %}
```

this is what it renders:

[image]

the random numbers and characters are the order_id in my order model 
the queryet is a list of orders  coming from my order model

but this not what i want , i want the access the data inside each queryset

Comment: Iterate over the querysets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the querysets. For example:

```
{% for qs in list %}
    <p>
    {% for order in qs %}
        {{ order }}
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here we thus iterate over the querysets `qs`, and for example render the `order`. You can thus render individual data of that order, for example `{{ order.pk }}` for the primary key.

Comment: thank you it works , actually i thought about doing that but i didn't get the second loop right , anyway thank you